# facebook oauth server-side in opera, explorer

Tags: facebook, oauth, opera, server-side, explorer

I'm using server side script for facebook authorization, it works perfect in Chrome and Mozilla, but in Opera and IE I got error.

My steps here below:
1. I open in popup www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri?} - nice, then I got 'code' and use it on my page

1. if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
       $curl = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&code='.$_GET['code']);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
       $s = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
       $access_token = explode('=', $s);
       $tempacc = explode('&', $access_token[1]);
       $access_token = $tempacc[0];

   ```
   if($access_token[1] != ''){

       $curl = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?&input_token='.$access_token.'&access_token='.$access_token);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
       $s = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
       $user = json_decode($s, true);
       print_r($user);
   //get error - Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => (#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app [type] => OAuthException [code] => 100 ) )
   ```

   }

and the same wokrs perfect in Chrome and Mozilla

Also I checked requested access_token in explorer here developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q={my_token} and it works

ANy ideas?

Comment: It looks like in Chrome I get right access_token, but in IE it's invalid...

Comment: Found, it was my fault I used developer account in chrome and simple in Opera. So also debug_token is not neccessary here, we should use other code.